# Is the zero set of a holomorphic function a complex manifold?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, analytic-functions, compact-manifolds

Is the zero set Z(f) of the holomorphic function $f$ a complex manifold? If not what could be the conditions required for it to be.

We know that for a topological space to be a complex manifold it has to be compact, have an open cover and homomorphisms from each open subset to the set of complex numbers such that they are holomorphic (analytic) and their inverses also.

Comment: What are the domain and range of $f$?

Comment: the domain and range are f:C^n→C

Comment: A complex manifold does not need to be compact.

Comment: In general it will not be a complex manifold. Take for example $f:\mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, \ f(z_1, z_2)= z_1\cdot z_2$. If you remove the origin from $Z(f)$, it becomes disconnected. Thus, it cannot be a complex manifold.

Comment: So one condition for Z(f) to be a complex manifold is for it to be connected? Any others you can think of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not always a complex manifold: Severn Schraven pointed out that the zero set of $f(z_1,z_2)=z_1z_2$ has a non-manifold point $(0,0)$; specifically, a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ in $Z(f)$ is not even homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, let alone being complex-diffeomorphic to it.

A sufficient condition is that the implicit function theorem applies to $f$, which for holomorphic functions $f:\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}$ means: at every point of the zero set $Z(f)$, at least one of the partial derivatives $\partial f/\partial z_k$ is nonzero. The implicit function theorem then provides a holomorphic parameterization of small pieces of $Z(f)$. It is discussed in [Analytic implicit function theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/73388) and [Implicit function theorem for several complex variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/489789).

(I used to think that nonvanishing of $\nabla f$ on $Z(f)$ is also *necessary* for $Z(f)$ to be a complex manifold, but Daniel Fischer pointed out that $f^2$ has the same zero set. )

Comment: The nonvanishing of $\nabla f$ isn't necessary, for example $Z(f^2) = Z(f)$. But locally that's the only way, if $Z(f)$ is a complex manifold near $\mathfrak{z}$, then there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $\mathfrak{z}$ and a holomorphic $g\colon U \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $Z(f)\cap U = Z(g)$, $\nabla g \neq 0$, and $f = g^k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$ on $U$.